# What core kernel-level IPC mechanisms exist in Linux?

Tags: linux, ipc

Off the top of my head, I know there are:

- pipes
- FIFO files / named pipes
- message queues
- shared memory
- semaphores
- signals

Is that the complete list?
Doing a bit of research, I think it [may be](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node7.html), but I want to be sure.

Answer (score 4):

From [IPC mechanisms on Linux - Introduction](http://www.chandrashekar.info/articles/linux-system-programming/introduction-to-linux-ipc-mechanims.html):

> The Linux kernel provides the following IPC mechanisms:
>
> ```
> Signals
> Anonymous Pipes
> Named Pipes or FIFOs
> SysV Message Queues
> POSIX Message Queues
> SysV Shared memory
> POSIX Shared memory
> SysV semaphores
> POSIX semaphores
> FUTEX locks
> File-backed and anonymous shared memory using mmap
> UNIX Domain Sockets
> Netlink Sockets
> Network Sockets
> Inotify mechanisms
> FUSE subsystem
> D-Bus subsystem
> ```

I would add shared file descriptors to the list.

Answer (score 2):

Do pseudo-ttys count? Those are the magic special files in `/dev/pts` under Linux. Older Unixes had a fixed number of pseudo-ttys as specially-named device files, I believe.

Pseudo-ttys are rather like pipes or socket pairs, but respond to different `ioctl()` calls.

Speaking of socket pairs, do the special file descriptors coming from a `socketpair()` system call count?

Also, bear in mind that there are two forms of shared memory. There's the older, more esoteric System V IPC shared memory, which isn't universally available any more, and there's using `mmap()` on a well-known file, with a `MAP_SHARED` flag.